# What kinds of encryption methods would contain all characters in the key?

Tags: cryptanalysis

Sorry if this question is worded poorly. I need generic help with a cipher and I'm not sure what jargon I should use to describe it. Any additional feedback in that regard would be appreciated.

I have a cipher that contains the characters 1-9, A-Z, and a-z in the cipher text(many of them repeat). To me, the cipher doesn't seem long enough for the plaintext to actually contain all letters of the original alphabet. Therefore, I'm assuming the encryption method attempts to use all of the characters in the key(1-9,A-Z,a-z) as a feature of the method. What encryption methods have this trait?

Comment: "Therefore, I'm assuming the encryption method attempts to use all of the characters in the key(1-9,A-Z,a-z) as a feature of the method"; actually, I suspect that's not an explicit design goal of the cipher (whatever it is); instead, it might just produce a random-looking output that is then mapped into the 1-9, A-Z, a-z characters (and possibly . and / as well; that would indicate that it's likely BASE64 encoded)

Comment: The actual ciphertext does contain '/' as well and I originally suspected it to be base64 but the resulting text didn't look useful. I appreciate the response but I'd really like to know if any methods have that trait intentionally and not just as a byproduct of a limited character set.

Comment: Standard encryption will produce all possible bytes with equal probability. Once you apply Base64 encoding on these bytes, you get `A`-`Z`, `a`-`z`, `0`-`9` and two special characters (typically `/` and `+`) with equal probability (often includes `=` padding as well, for no good reason).

Comment: Sounds like I'm likely wrong with my assumption that this is an actual trait of the cipher and it's actually just encryption doing what encryption is supposed to do. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them, and all of them.

Modern symmetric ciphers take a binary key, a binary IV and binary encoded plaintext and turn that into binary encoded ciphertext. In the ciphertext all bits are as likely as the result should be (or is generally) indistinguishable from random. Even for RSA the last operation is I2OSP (integer to octet stream) which turns the ciphertext into binary.

Sometimes however it's required to send the ciphertext over a textual interface. In that case only the valid characters of the alphabet ("code page") of the character encoding can be used. In those circumstances the ciphertext is usually converted to base 64 to comply with these rules. The encoding is however *completely separate* from the algorithm of the cipher.

So in general the base 64 encoding of ciphertext - by itself - tells very little about the encryption method used.  If you're lucky the *binary contents* of the encoding consists of a *container format* such as CMS or PGP which will specify the exact algorithm used. Otherwise you'll probably have to make an (educated) guess.